# image change getText

Tags: java, android

In this code example, I need to add a picture
But I want to add the text
How can I do it
how can I solve this problem
And my code:
thank you for help

```
package com.example.quizapp;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView countLabel;
    private ImageView questionImage;
    private Button answerBtn1;
    private Button answerBtn2;
    private Button answerBtn3;
    private Button answerBtn4;

    private String rightAnswer;
    private int rightAnswerCount = 0;
    private int quizCount = 1;

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> quizArray = new ArrayList<>();

    String quizData[][] = {
            // {"Image Name", "Right Answer", "Choice1", "Choice2", "Choice3"}
            {"image_circle", "circle", "triangle", "square", "hexagon"},
            {"image_triangle", "triangle", "circle", "square", "pentagon"},
            {"image_square", "square", "triangle", "pentagon", "hexagon"},
            {"image_pentagon", "pentagon", "circle", "triangle", "hexagon"},
            {"image_hexagon", "hexagon", "triangle", "pentagon", "circle"},
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        countLabel = findViewById(R.id.countLabel);
        questionImage = findViewById(R.id.questionImage);
        answerBtn1 = findViewById(R.id.answerBtn1);
        answerBtn2 = findViewById(R.id.answerBtn2);
        answerBtn3 = findViewById(R.id.answerBtn3);
        answerBtn4 = findViewById(R.id.answerBtn4);

        // Create quizArray from quizData.
        for (int i = 0; i < quizData.length; i++) {
            // Prepare array.
            ArrayList<String> tmpArray = new ArrayList<>();
            tmpArray.add(quizData[i][0]); // Image Name
            tmpArray.add(quizData[i][1]); // Right Answer
            tmpArray.add(quizData[i][2]); // Choice1
            tmpArray.add(quizData[i][3]); // Choice2
            tmpArray.add(quizData[i][4]); // Choice3

            // Add tmpArray to quizArray.
            quizArray.add(tmpArray);
        }

        showNextQuiz();
    }

    public void showNextQuiz() {

        // Update quizCountLabel.
        countLabel.setText("Q" + quizCount);

        // Generate random number between 0 and 4 (quizArray's size -1)
        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNum = random.nextInt(quizArray.size());

        // Pick one quiz set.
        ArrayList<String> quiz = quizArray.get(randomNum);

        // Set Image and Right Answer.
        // Array format: {"Image Name", "Right Answer", "Choice1", "Choice2", "Choice3"}
        questionImage.setImageResource(
                getResources().getIdentifier(quiz.get(0), "drawable", getPackageName()));
        rightAnswer = quiz.get(1);

        // Remove "Image Name" from quiz and shuffle choices.
        quiz.remove(0);
        Collections.shuffle(quiz);

        // Set choices.
        answerBtn1.setText(quiz.get(0));
        answerBtn2.setText(quiz.get(1));
        answerBtn3.setText(quiz.get(2));
        answerBtn4.setText(quiz.get(3));

        // Remove this quiz from quizArray.
        quizArray.remove(randomNum);

    }

    public void checkAnswer(View view) {

        // Get pushed button.
        Button answerBtn = findViewById(view.getId());
        String btnText = answerBtn.getText().toString();

        String alertTitle;

        if (btnText.equals(rightAnswer)) {
            // Correct!!
            alertTitle = "Correct!";
            rightAnswerCount++;

        } else {
            // Wrong
            alertTitle = "Wrong...";
        }

        // Create Dialog.
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(alertTitle);
        builder.setMessage("Answer : " + rightAnswer);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                if (quizArray.size() < 1) {
                    // quizArray is empty.
                    showResult();

                } else {
                    quizCount++;
                    showNextQuiz();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.show();
    }

    public void showResult() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Result");
        builder.setMessage(rightAnswerCount + " / 5");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Try Again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                recreate();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Quit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

Hello to everyone
In this code example, I need to add a picture
But I want to add the text
How can I do it
how can I solve this problem
And my code:
thank you for help

Comment: `I need to add a picture But I want to add the text` ??? What is it ? Your question is pretty much vague. Explain your problem properly .

Comment: sorry for my bad english this code; photo question-answer. need to add photos.ı want change "quizData" in "image name" change question content. image name alternately "question content"

Comment: in quizdata "Image name" change "quiz text" please help me.

Answer (score 1):

**TextView** comes with 4 compound drawables, one for each of **left**, **top**, **right** and **bottom**.

You can use **TextView** as a **Button** with its clickListner.

In your case, you do not need the Button at all. Just replace your button with Textview add `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/your_drawable_image"` to your TextView.

For more info see **setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(int,int,int,int)** : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)